# Any subset of a topological space can be given sub space topology. Can any subset of a manifold be given sub-manifold properties?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

What I mean by this question is can we define an atlas for the given subset of the manifold using the charts of the original manifold so that the set is a manifold? By manifold, I mean manifold with or without boundary.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider the union of the $x$- and $y$-axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: all other points except "0" are homeomorphic to an open interval. Because of point zero, this is not a submanifold, right?

Comment: Correct, if zero means the origin.

Comment: Thank you for the answer